# how to convert djvu files to some files? and use djvused command

Tags: conversion, djvu, windows

when i use this command:

**djvused  aaa.djvu -e 'select 10; save-page-with b.djvu'**

output is:

```
D:\Program Files\DjVuLibre>djvused  aaa.djvu -e 'select 10; save-page-with b.djvu'
Simple DjVu file manipulation program

Usage: djvused [options] djvufile
Executes scripting commands on djvufile.
Script command come either from a script file (option -f),
from the command line (option -e), or from stdin (default).

Options are
  -v               -- verbose
  -f <scriptfile>  -- take commands from a file
  -e <script>      -- take commands from the command line
  -s               -- save after execution
  -u               -- produces utf8 instead of escaping non ascii chars
  -n               -- do not save anything


Commands
--------
The following commands can be separated by newlines or semicolons.
Comment lines start with '#'.  Commands usually operate on pages and files
specified by the "select" command.  All pages and files are initially selected.
A single page must be selected before executing commands marked with a period.
Commands marked with an underline do not use the selection

   ls                     -- list all pages/files
   n                      -- list pages count
   dump                   -- shows IFF structure
   size                   -- prints page width and height in html friendly way
   select                 -- selects the entire document
   select <id>            -- selects a single page/file by name or page number
   select-shared-ant      -- selects the shared annotations file
   create-shared-ant      -- creates and select the shared annotations file
   showsel                -- displays currently selected pages/files
 . print-ant              -- prints annotations
 . print-merged-ant       -- prints annotations including the shared annotations
 . print-meta             -- prints file metadatas (a subset of the annotations
   print-txt              -- prints hidden text using a lisp syntax
   print-pure-txt         -- print hidden text without coordinates
 _ print-outline          -- print outline (bookmarks)
 . print-xmp              -- print xmp annotations
   output-ant             -- dumps ant as a valid cmdfile
   output-txt             -- dumps text as a valid cmdfile
   output-all             -- dumps ant and text as a valid cmdfile
 . set-ant [<antfile>]    -- copies <antfile> into the annotation chunk
 . set-meta [<metafile>]  -- copies <metafile> into the metadata annotation tag
 . set-txt [<txtfile>]    -- copies <txtfile> into the hidden text chunk
 . set-xmp [<xmpfile>]    -- copies <xmpfile> into the xmp metadata annotation tag
 _ set-outline [<bmfile>] -- sets outline (bootmarks)
 _ set-thumbnails [<sz>]  -- generates all thumbnails with given size
   remove-ant             -- removes annotations
   remove-meta            -- removes metadatas without changing other annotations
   remove-txt             -- removes hidden text
 _ remove-outline         -- removes outline (bookmarks)
 . remove-xmp             -- removes xmp metadata from annotation chunk
 _ remove-thumbnails      -- removes all thumbnails
 . set-page-title <title> -- sets an alternate page title
 . save-page <name>       -- saves selected page/file as is
 . save-page-with <name>  -- saves selected page/file, inserting all included files
 _ save-bundled <name>    -- saves as bundled document under fname
 _ save-indirect <name>   -- saves as indirect document under fname
 _ save                   -- saves in-place
 _ help                   -- prints this message

Interactive example:
--------------------
  Type
    % djvused -v file.djvu
  and play with the commands above

Command line example:
---------------------
  Save all text and annotation chunks as a djvused script with
    % djvused file.djvu -e output-all > file.dsed
  Then edit the script with any text editor.
  Finally restore the modified text and annotation chunks with
    % djvused file.djvu -f file.dsed -s
  You may use option -v to see more messages


D:\Program Files\DjVuLibre>
```

how can fix this?

Comment: This question ask for clarifications about an answer to another related question, I voted to close this one as duplicate. All necessary clarifications and further help should be addressed on the other question.

Comment: I agree; makes more sense to clarify an existing question rather than open a slightly updated one. Makes it harder to search through answers when there's a sea of similar ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easier solution for this issue is to change the single quotes with double quotes. The have a different function under the DOS/Windows command prompt than under the common Linux shells.

```
djvused  aaa.djvu -e "select 10; save-page-with b.djvu"
```

---

You can easily test the different workings of the single and double quotes by doing:

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1:]" "abc def" 'uvw xyz'
```

which gives you the **3** element list:

```
['abc def', "'uvw", "xyz'"]
```

Comment: I got an email from the developers with similar info %-) I cannot delete my answer, otherwise I would have. And yes I am a Unix user, Windows only if absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Holger, the command:
djvused  aaa.djvu -e "select 10; save-page-with b.djvu"
is also work, I think how can i know about change single quotes with double quotes myself :D:D:D.
I don't see this tip even in
http://djvu.sourceforge.net/doc/man/djvused.html